# Loaded audio playing using jquery and html5

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to play audio file on button onclick. It is working file in my local computer. However when I uploaded it on online it take long time for loding because in every button there have different audio file.

Here is the url: http://www.foodworlds.info/music/

Please give me a solution how It loaded asynchronously.

Comment: Asynchronous loads for audio objects is not working across all browsers. iOS (iPad and iPhone) is one of the platforms where you can't expect this to work.

Comment: If you can splice the audio tracks together, you can use audio sprites which is much more reliable.